# User-defined object containing pointer breaks when stored in array

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

When I store a plain `int` in `A` and perform a simple get function:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int p;
public:
    void setint(int p_x);
    int getint();
};

void A::setint(int p_x) {p = p_x;} // set p (type int)

int A::getint() {return p;} // get p (type int)

int main()
{
    A arr_a[5];
    arr_a[0].getint();
}
```

it compiles and exits with code `0`. However when I change `int` to `int*` and try to do the same:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int* p;
public:
    void setint(int p_x);
    int getint();
};

void A::setint(int p_x) {*p = p_x;} // set int pointed to by p (type int)

int A::getint() {return *p;} // get int pointed to by p (type int)

int main()
{
    A arr_a[5];
    arr_a[0].getint();
}
```

it compiles fine but exits with code `3221225477`. Why is this so and is there still a way I can store pointers in `A` and store `A` in arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd case `A arr_a[5]` just create a array that contains 5 A. but
for every A, the pointer is an undefined number (maybe 0x0), so `*p` is a undefined behavior. You should add `A::A()` and `A::~A()` to manage your pointer in your class
just like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int *p;

public:
    A();
    ~A();
    void setint(int p_x);
    int getint();
};

A::A() : p(new int) {}
A::~A() { delete p; }

void A::setint(int p_x) { *p = p_x; } // set int pointed to by p (type int)

int A::getint() { return *p; } // get int pointed to by p (type int)

int main()
{
    A arr_a[5];
    arr_a[0].getint();
}
```

Comment: my bad, I didn't even realise that pointers should primarily be used to access data on heap. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a **serious flaw**. Both of your given code snippets (case 1 and case 2 in your question) have **undefined behavior**. Lets see how it is

**Case I**: Code Snippet 1

In your code snippet 1, since the data member `p` is a built in type and you've not initialized it, so `p` has a **garbage value** and using(accessing) this value can lead to **undefined behavior** which is exactly what is happening in your case.

When you wrote:

```
 A arr_a[5];//this creates a 1D array of size 5 having elements of type `A` but the elements are default initialized 
 arr_a[0].getint();//this result in undefined behavior
```

The above statement creates a 1D array of size 5 having elements of type `A`. The **problem** is that since you have not initialized this array, its elements are **default initialized** which means that the value of data member `p` is also default initialized. But since you didn't use **in-class initializers** for variable `p`, `p` has garbage value and this leads to **undefined behavior**.

You can confirm this by looking at the output [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oi6LXu6Dt7Zt6HoV).

**Solution to Case I**

You can solve this by initializing the data member `p` using **in-class initializer** as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int p = 0;//USE IN-CLASS INITIALIZER
public:
    void setint(int p_x);
    int getint();
};

void A::setint(int p_x) {p = p_x;} // set p (type int)

int A::getint() {return p;} // get p (type int)

int main()
{
    A arr_a[5];
    std::cout<<arr_a[0].getint();//now ok because we have initilaized p
}
```

**Case II**: Code Snippet 2

In this case the only difference is that now the data member `p` is a pointer to int that is `int*`. Similar to last case the pointer variable has a **garbage value** which can lead to **undefined behavior** if you try to use it as you did inside your main function by writing:

```
A arr_a[5];//create a 1D array of objects `A` but the elements(A objects) are default initialized  
arr_a[0].getint();//this result in undefined behavior
```

**Solution to Case II**

You can solve this by initializing the data member `p` using **in-class initializer** as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
    int* p = nullptr;//USE IN-CLASS INITIALIZER
public:
    void setint(int p_x);
    int getint();
    //other members like constructor and destructor to allocate and deallocate memory
    //so that getint and setint doesn't dereference nullptr
};

void A::setint(int p_x) 
{    if(p!=nullptr)// add a check here to see p isn't null
     {
        *p = p_x;
         
     }
     else 
    {
        std::cout<<"WARNING: Dereferencing a nullptr can lead to UB";
    }

} 

int A::getint() // add a check here to see p isn't null
{   if(p!= nullptr)
    {
    std::cout<<"yes"<<std::endl;   
    return *p;
      
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"WARNING: Dereferencing a nullptr can lead to UB";
        return -1;
    }
} 

int main()
{
    A arr_a[5];
    arr_a[0].getint();//now ok(assuming `p` isn't nullptr) because we have initilaized p 
}
```

### Summary

Both of the code snippets that you gave have **undefined behavior**. You can solve both of them by using **in-class initilaizers** to initialize data member `p` to a default value.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Why the pointer is always `nullptr`? To make it `nullptr` we must initialize it to `nullptr`. Also neither function treat it(the pointer) as an `int`. The problem is that both of them use the value of unitialized member `p` by calling `getint()`. The accepted answer doesn't even talk about case I.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I know that and that is why i didn't use/call `setint`. Also, to add the constructor and destructor is OP's responsibility. I just pointed out the fundamental flaw in OP's current code snippet(like actually calling `getint` which leads to UB). And showed how that can be solved by using in-class initilalizer. Also, before dereferencing `p` in both `getint` and `setint` the OP should check whether `p` is not `nullptr` but again i am not responsible for adding the check. **Second**, The 1st code snippet of OP has also UB, and the accepted answer doesn't deal(address it) with it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer or dereferencing a null pointer is the same problem. That is why i added a check in the edited version of case II. The OP's question was regarding why he/she was getting the exit code mentioned and i explained there reason. Also, the accepted answer is incomplete itself(because of it doesn't tell . Can you tell me why my answer still "feels" incorrect to you(even after i have mentioned in the code side comment that you(OP) must add constructor and destructor by yourself)?